# thread and process programming

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am a newbie Python programmer. I interested in parallel and concurrent programming.  I understand the difference between process and thread but I confused about how multiprocessing and threading work.
If my program A is -

```
from multiprocessing import Process
for i in range(50):
    p = Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
```

Does it will generate 50 processes on 1 CPU or distribute on  4 CPUs (my laptop has 4 CPUs 2 Cores) and same question but change program A to program B
my program B is -

```
from threading import Thread
for i in range(50)
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
```

In program B all threads depend on 1 process or not?

Explain this to me, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiprocessing creates new subprocess, which can be run on multiple cores simultaneously.

Threading, as its name, will create a thread. Multiple threads share the same memory space, and GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) will prevent them to concurrent write. Due to GIL, threads cannot be spawned on multiple cores.

So, A will run on 4 CPUs, while B will run on one.